# How to get id of dynamically generated button when its clicked

Tags: java, android, dynamically-generated

I used a loop to create some dynamically generated buttons and in the same loop, I defined `OnClickListener`.

The summarized code:

```
for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
    Button button = new Button(this);
    button.setId(j);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(view v) {
            //Code
        }
    });
}
```

If any of them are clicked, then `onClick` is activated and all of them run the same code.
I wanna know how to get the `id` of clicked buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your onClickListener, there is a supplied `View v` parameter, that was basically your button, so just call: `v.getId()` should get your the button's id.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        Log.d('LOG', v.getId());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```kotlin
/**
 * Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when a view is clicked.
 */
public interface OnClickListener {
    /**
     * Called when a view has been clicked.
     *
     * @param v The view that was clicked.
     */
    void onClick(View v);
}
```

Above interface is registered for every view `setOnClickListener()`, so if any user clicks the view, `onClick(View v)` method will be invoked.
That time we get to know about all the property of the view. So, we get the Views Id by calling this method `view.getId()`.